# How to retrieve data sent by Infrared sensors on an Arduino to a local host, using jQuery?

Tags: jquery, node.js, arduino, localhost, httpserver

I have a few Infrared sensors connected to an Arduino. These sensors send 1s when no object detected and 0s when an object is detected. I have created an http webserver using node.js. I am able to see the changes (0’s and 1’s) on a localhost when I listen on an specific port number.

Now, I am trying to access these 0’s and 1’s using jQuery to link them to HTML code. I have tried using .load(); and .get(); with the localhost URL and the port number and it doesn’t work. Maybe this is not the way to access and retrieve the data that is sent to the localhost.

Please guide me on the steps that this can be achieved.

Node.js Code:

```
var dgram = require("dgram");
var server = dgram.createSocket("udp4");
var fs = require('fs');
var http = require("http");

var crlf = new Buffer(2);
crlf[0] = 0xD; //CR - Carriage return character
crlf[1] = 0xA; //LF - Line feed character

var sensorData=[];

server.on("message", function (msg, rinfo) {
   sensorData = msg.toString();

 console.log(msg.toString());
 fs.appendFile('mydata.txt', msg.toString() + crlf, encoding='utf8');
 return;

  var value = '';
  for(var k=0; k<msg.length ; k++) {
    var v = msg.readUInt8(k);
    if (v != 1) { console.log(k) ;};
  } 
 // console.log(msg.toString());
   return;


 var value = msg.readUInt8(2);
  if (value != 1) {
 //every time new data arrives do this:
   console.log("server got: " , msg.readUInt8(2) , " from " + rinfo.address + ":"     +      rinfo.port); // you can comment this line out
  fs.appendFile('mydata.txt', msg.readUInt8(0) + crlf, encoding='utf8');//write the      value to file and add CRLF for line break
} 
});

 server.on("listening", function () {
   var address = server.address();
   console.log("server listening " + address.address + ":" + address.port); 
 });

 server.bind(6000); //listen to udp traffic on port 6000

 http.createServer(function (request, response) {

  response.writeHead(200);
  response.write(sensorData);
  response.end();


}).listen(1000);
```

HTML:

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>Hamed's Website</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="website.css">
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1    /jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.9.2/jquery-ui.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="website.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="P1-1"></div>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Can you post your HTML code? How are you listening/seeing 0's and 1's  on local host? Where is the code that listens to a specific port?

Comment: @lucidgold, I added the code. When I wanna view the data I just type in "localhost:1000", in my browser and I see the data.

Answer (score 1):

Since you are using node.js, try utilizing the NPM package [johnny-five](https://www.npmjs.org/package/johnny-five) which is a framework for working with Arduino.  Check out the IR Motion example at https://github.com/rwaldron/johnny-five/blob/master/docs/ir-motion.md

**Side Note, the creator of johnny-five is Rick Waldron who is also a contributor to jQuery.*